# How can I mix multi-channel input device down to mono?

Tags: catalina, audio, microphone, soundflower

I have a microphone and Soundflower installed, and an aggregate device set up in Audio MIDI setup to mix the two together. My mic has two channels, and Soundflower has both a 2 channel and a 64 channel device. I just put them all together.

[image: Screenshot of aggregate input device]

The problem is, I'm trying to use this as a "mic" input for Microsoft Teams (which [does not support multi-channel input audio](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/41022388-multi-channel-audio-usb-interface-compatibility)), which seems to only use one channel. With the settings as my screenshot shows, people can hear only my microphone; but if I swap the order of the devices so that Soundflower is first, people can hear the Soundflower output, and not my mic.

I'd like to mix these channels down to a single channel that I can use as the mic input. Is this possible (without external hardware?)

Comment: Been a while since I played with this but I *think* it may do the trick https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/

Comment: @SteveChambers I'm not trying to record, I need this for live audio. I think this tool is for recordings. :(

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. It does appear to have live output! Bit pricey though. If you want to share it as an answer I'll be glad to upvote it, but will wait for free solutions too.

Comment: Half your problem with this task it that you have to be able to route what would nominally be an 'output' to another input as opposed to 'one of your regular outputs'. This needs some clever juggling, which Rogue Amoeba are very good at. Soundflower  used to be a pretty decent alternative at one time, but got flaky around Mavericks & I haven't used it since, so I really can't remember how it used to route. Rogue Amoeba basically bought Soundflower [also with a caretaker role for a time]  from the original owners [Cycling'74] & eventually came up with what they have now.

Comment: See https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases for the current caretaker of the original Soundflower [I think he used to be involved with Cycling'74 but I'm not absolutely certain] however I think this funcionality used to be achieved with the now defunct Soundflowerbed.

Comment: I am using the latest Soundflower and it does do the "right thing" in that it takes the "output" of the soundflower devices and adds them as channels in the "input" I show here in my post. I know it's doing it because if I swap the order of the devices, I can get my desktop audio to go into my "mic" in MS Teams, but then my actual microphone doesn't go through. It's a shame they retired Soundflowerbed and now there only seems to be a paid option :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since I have played with Audio Hijak but I do believe it may do what you need it to do, and a lot of other audio tricks handy for people who do podcasts and audio mixing, though not for free.

https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/

Comment: I tried this and it was very easy to get working. The $60 price is painful but the only promising alternative I found, iShowU instant, didn't work for live redirection, only recording. So this is the only solution I have found thus far so I'm accepting this as the answer